# I was stupid and accidentally put my old 3DS through the wash

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Some time ago, I had kept my 3DS in the pocket of my big heavy winter coat. However, I had mistakenly left it there and it ended up in the wash. It had only been in there a few minutes, but it was soaked and did not function at all. I immediately put it in a bag of dry, warm rice and left it there for about 3 days. Much to my dismay, it still did not function and has not since. Everything is dry, but I'm quite worried for my 3DS. I don't know what to do. I have a whole bunch of games on it and I need it to be able to transfer them to my newer model. The only indication of function is when I plug in the AC adapter, the charge light turns on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Contact Nintendo on this.  They can probably retrieve data based off the serial number or something.

Comment: I would remove the battery while you're at it. It's a very simple process only requiring a Philips screwdriver.  Test if the system works with AC, but without the battery.

Comment: I would stop trying to charge it or getting it to turn on, as doing so may result in further damage.

Answer (score 4):

If you bought the games through the market, they are linked to your Nintendo Network ID. Just link your newer model to that ID and you should be able to download the games.

As for the SD card, test it with any computer. It stores some data depending on the game, as well as photos taken with the 3DS and StreetPass info, which isn't very critical; worst-case scenario, it won't work anymore and that data will be lost, so you'll have to get a new one. But test it first.

Even if it doesn't work, you might be able to recover the info inside, but you'll have to look for an expert.